# Using Django model inheritence to clone a table

Tags: django

I have a user table and want to create a backup table named deleted_users that is a clone of the user table. When a user gets deleted I want to move the record from the user table to the deleted_users table.

```
class LCUser(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "user" 

class LCUserDeleted(LCUser):
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "deleted_users"
```

I tried as above but this creates the user table with all the fields and a deleted_users table with 2 fields ( lcusers_ptr_id and deleted_at ), How can I create the 2nd table with all the fields without typing everything one by one ?

Comment: I think this is bad design. Why would you want to have separate table for almost exact same structure? Why not just have one table with `deleted_at` field and if this field is `None` than user is not deleted and vice versa.

Comment: assume each record is a user in our system. if the user gets deleted and tries to create the same user using his email it will not allow since the email must be unique. Is there a better way to handle this situation  ?

Comment: @WilletteLynch: Django already has an "is_active" field, if it becomes False then the user is considered inactive. What if you have foreign keys to users somewhere in your system, should that data all disappear when a user becomes inactive / is deleted?

Comment: 'email must be unique', this will give you more trouble than you're expecting, what do you think will happen if i create an account, delete it, make another one with the same email, and delete than one too?

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active

Comment: You can set `unique_together` opiton in model's `Meta` for `email` and `deleted_at`. Only tricky part is that this way it will not apply constraint if `deleted_at` is null. So by default you will have to set `deleted_at` to start of epoch, and not `null`

Comment: I'm not using the django user table. This is a separate table for system users. so I don't think i can use is_active. as for FK's pointing to users, its ok if they get deleted as I have on delete cascade. I don't need the FK data. Setting unique_together wont solve my problem, as this is connected to a tastypie API and i would have to rewrite authentication to check for the deleted flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to achieve what you're looking for you actually need 3 models, one abstract one and two actual models:

```
class BaseLCUser(models.Model):
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=100,unique=True)
  password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  last_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
  class Meta:
      abstract = True

class LCUser(BaseLCUser):
  class Meta:
    db_table = "user"

class LCUserDeleted(BaseLCUser):
  deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
  class Meta:
      db_table = "deleted_users"
```

By using an abstract model as a common parent Django will actually create full tables for each of the models.

## Edit:

Regarding the unique E-mail, you might want to avoid setting it to unique on a database level, and control it through your forms, because if you create and account with email example@example.org, delete it, create another one with the same email and delete than new account, you will be trying to have two deleted users with the same email.

another option would be to remove the email field from the abstract Model, and put it in each of the child models, being unique only in the not deleted user.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think my design is flawed ? is there a better / simpler way to get this done ?

Comment: @WilletteLynch while this is definitely not the best way to go, i don't know how advanced in development this project is, so if it is possible you should probably at least consider using logical deletion and see if it disrupts too much of the existing project to be worth the refactoring.